# why feel urge to urinate when riding a pirate ship

Tags: triggers, urinary-system, urination

A pirate ship is an amusement ride that throw people up and down. Why the sense of acute acceleration, hypogravity and hypergravity make me feel an urge to urinate, even if my bladder is empty?

Comment: Do you still have the issue after you get off?

Comment: I also experience this when I am riding amusement park rides. I am 52 years of age. I have all my life and have no clue why. I can only take so many rides before I just need to stop due to it becoming more and more uncomfortable. It is only when changing direction from up to down or vice versa. Likewise my bladder is empty and I have no UTI or any other health condition.